# Sets of convergence of independent random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I'm reading a claim on p. 30 of Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability* (1st ed.) that implies the following claim:

> **Claim:** Suppose $\xi_1, \xi_2, \dotsc:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ are independent random variables. Suppose $\mathcal{F}_1,
>  \mathcal{F}_2, \dotsc$ are the sigma algebras generated by these
>   random variables, form the join of the tail $\mathcal{T}_k = \vee_{i=k}^\infty \mathcal{F}_i$,
>   i.e. the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_k, \mathcal{F}_{k+1} \dotsc$.
>   Now take the tail algebra $\mathcal{T} = \cap_{j=1}^\infty \mathcal{T}_j$. Form the sum of the $\xi_i$, $S_n =
>  \xi_1 + \dotsb + \xi_n$. Then the sets of convergence of $(S_n)$ and
>   $(S_n/n)$ are $\mathcal{T}$-measurable.

He refers to lemma 1.9, which says that various limits of measurable functions to $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ are themselves measurable. I don't see his logic...it would work if $S_n$ were $\mathcal{T}$-measurable, and so their limit would be $\mathcal{T}$-measurable. but $S_n$ are not $\mathcal{T}$-measurable: for instance $\xi_1 + \xi_2$ isn't measurable with respect to $\vee_{i=3}^\infty \mathcal{F}_i \supset \mathcal{T}$ in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic is:

$$\text{Set of convergence of }\xi_1 + \xi_2 + \dotsb = \text{Set of convergence of } \xi_k + \xi_{k+1} + \dotsb$$

and the latter is $\mathcal{T}_k$ measurable. So just let $k$ increase and this shows that the set of convergence is $\mathcal{T}_k$ measurable for all $k$ and so $\mathcal{T}$ measurable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the book so I can't comment on Kallenberg's argument, but here's how I would prove it:

If we use the Cauchy criterion for convergence and translate this criterion into events, we can write
$$ \{\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n\;\mathrm{exists}\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m\geq n\geq N}\{|S_m-S_n|<\frac{1}{k}\}$$
(using $\frac{1}{k}$ instead of a general $\varepsilon>0$ to make the outer intersection a countable one). If we define
$$ E_{k,N}=\bigcap_{m\geq n\geq N}\{|S_m-S_n|<\frac{1}{k}\}$$
then $E_{k,N}\in\mathcal{T}_N$, and for each $k$ we have
$$E_{k,1}\subset E_{k,2}\subset E_{k,3}\subset\cdots$$
so the union 
$$ \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}E_{k,N}$$
is a tail event for each $k$, which proves that $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n\;\mathrm{exists}\}$ is a tail event. Something similar should work for $\frac{S_n}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks. Look at my above answer, if you care to.

Comment: @carmichael561 may I ask you how you conclude from that $E_{k,N }\in \mathcal {T_N } $ that for any $N $: $\cup_ {n=1 } ^{\infty } E_{k,n } \in \mathcal {T_N } $?

Comment: from the decreasing property I can see that we have $\cup _{n=N } ^{\infty } E_{k,n } \in \mathcal {T_N } $ but what about $\cup _{n=1 } ^{N-1 } E_{k,n } $?

Comment: @MrFranzén: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but note that $\cup_{N=1}^{\infty}E_{k,N}=\cup_{N=2}^{\infty}E_{k,N}=\cdots$ because $E_{k,1}\subset E_{k,2}\subset E_{k,3}\subset\cdots$