# Arithmetic means of independent random variables converge/diverge almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I found this result from [Corollary 3.14, Olav Kallenberg. Foundations of Modern Probability, 2ed]:

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ be independent random variables, and put $S_n = \xi_1 + \ldots \xi_n$. Then each of the sequences $(S_n)$ and $(S_n/n)$ is either a.s. convergent or a.s. divergent. For the latter sequence, the possible limit is a.s. degenerate.

This was established in the book by stating (without giving details) that the set of convergence of $(S_n)$ and $(S_n/n)$ are $\mathcal{T}$-measurable, and thus have probabilities in ${0,1}$ by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. Here, $\mathcal{T} = \bigcap_{n\geq 0}\sigma\{\xi_{k}; k > n\}$ is the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

I was able to convince myself that the set of $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $\{S_n(\omega)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence (and thus convergent) belongs to the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

However, I'm still unable to see why the event $\{ (S_n/n) \text{ converges} \}$ is also in $\mathcal{T}$, and further, the limit of $(S_n/n)$ , if exists, is a $\mathcal{T}$-measurable random variable. I've been struggling with this for weeks and would be very grateful if someone can show me a proof, or pointing to a paper where this was proved.

Answer (score 1):

I found that a similar question was asked and answered in

[Sets of convergence of independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932364/sets-of-convergence-of-independent-random-variables?rq=1)

I'll just supply a few more details below.

Applying to the sequence $(S_n/n)$, what we need is that the following are equivalent:

i) $(S_n/n)$ converges.

ii) $\left(\frac{S_n - S_m}n \right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

The equivalence of these two statements could be seen straightforwardly. Then, we can break down the set of convergence of $(S_n/n)$ into intersection of nested sets, each belong to $\sigma\{ \xi_{k}; k > m\}$.

We can see why $\lim (S_n/n)$ should be measurable wrt the tail sigma-field by realizing that if such thing exists, it will be the same with the limits of all sequences $(\frac{S_n - S_k}{k})$, each of which are $\mathcal{T}_k$-measurable.

Comment: What fails when one tries to apply this argument to show that $(S_n)$ is a.s. degenerate? After all, the set on which it converges is a tail event and thus the possible limit is a random variable on the restriction of the tail field, and since the restriction is trivial shouldn't the limit be a.s. degenerate?